# How to speed up creating Waypoints?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I am attaching a waypoint to 2000 elements on the page, because I want to trigger a different event for each one.  I have tried the noframework way as well as using jquery, and each one adds about 20 seconds to the loading of my page.  Is there a technique I can use to attach waypoints to a lot of elements without it slowing down my page load?  Thanks.

Jquery version (call once):

```
    var waypoints = $('[data-waypointidentifier="iswaypoint"]').waypoint({
            handler: function (direction) {
                waypointHandler(direction, this);
            }
        });
```

No Framework version (called once for each of the 2000 elements):

```
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
            document.getElementById('element-waypoint1'),
            handler: function (direction) {
                waypointHandler(direction, this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, perhaps someone can assist you. It might also help to include a representative chunk of HTML.

Comment: Be sure to post here how you attached it with your example code.

Comment: Not me, just added notes.

Comment: Can you use classes? What happens with a slightly different instantiation `$('.iswaypoint').waypoint(function (direction) {waypointHandler(direction, this); });`  Note the passed handler, not an option

Comment: One other thought is to attach after the page loads i.e. in a setTimeout.  OR in the window.onload event.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I did try with setTimeout.  The page does finish loading, but then immediately freezes up once the handler fires to create the waypoints.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I tried passing the handler, instead of an option, but it did not speed up execution any.

Comment: OK, I know we are getting a bit off topic a bit but just to try to suggest some possible things:   **To isolate to JUST the plugin, make the function/handler do minimal - just assign some variable or whatever, see if that has any impact at all**. 2000 is probably outside the scope that most people would do on this type functionality but I am NOT judging that as I have had to optimize performance on stuff myself on edge cases.  Might have to debounce (I think throttle is in the plugin already)

Comment: You might also try` someElements.on('waypoint.reached', function(event, direction) {
       // make it rain
    });`   One thing to note is the project is (apparently) not being updated - no changes since Sep 2016 that I see here: https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Comment: One other thought is to pass `enabled` false on the options then enable after attachment and after all your page loads and everything else is done, perhaps even in a delay via `setTimeout` etc.  `waypoint.enable()` so that it would not fire if you have a large (as it appears) DOM and it re-flows a lot on the load. http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/enable/  I base this on this issue https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/558

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I instantiated all elements as disabled, and never enabled them at any point.  The handler attachment took exactly as long as when the waypoints were enabled by default.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, the only thing happening is that I am attaching the handler.  I have not actually gotten to the point of adding any logic in the handler, since I cannot overcome this performance issue.  It seems as though the plugin was not designed to handle so many elements, which is a real shame, because it appears to be the only plugin that I can find that does exactly what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161547/discussion-between-mark-schultheiss-and-eric).

Answer (score 0):

<s>**This is not really an answer** BUT does demonstrate the issue in near lowest form.</s>

EDIT: This is perhaps a bit of a workaround hack now.  Modified to simply attach in chunks.

NOTE: you will have to modify the last chunk - mine had even numbers at 2000 which I "chunked" in groups and then set a bound timeout to attach them.  It still takes just as long but makes the situation slightly less visible while/until they all attach.

```js
// approx times to attach (not definitive)
// - note each increment nearly doubles times, not linear
// super simple test, chrome, prob more on most computers
// var punchCount = 250;   // 150ms
// var punchCount = 500;   // 500ms
// var punchCount = 1000; // 2350ms
// var punchCount = 1500; // 4700ms
var punchCount = 2000; // 8750ms

function initme() {
  var addme = $('<div class="facepunch" data-iam="-1">hi</div>');
  var addgroup = $('<div>start</div>');
  for (var i = punchCount; i > 0; i--) {
    addme = $('<div class="facepunch">hi</div>').data('iam', i);
    addme.appendTo(addgroup);
  }
  $('#punchme').append(addgroup);
}
var t0 = performance.now();

console.log('init 1');
initme();

var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to initme took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

console.log('before 1');

function waypointHandler(direction, me) {
  // NOOO... this will kill your perf console.log(direction, me);
  var newt = "howdy " + $(me.element).data('iam');
  $(me.element).text(newt + " " + direction);
}
t0 = performance.now();
console.log('before 2');
var waypoints = {};

function createWaysChunk(begin, end) {
  console.log(begin, end, $('.facepunch').slice(begin, end).length);

  $('.facepunch').slice(begin, end).waypoint({
    // enabled: false,//no perf benefit
    handler: function(direction) {
      waypointHandler(direction, this); // "this.element" is the element
    }
  });
}

function createWays() {
  t0 = performance.now();
  var chunksize = 40;
  var y = punchCount / chunksize; // 250
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < chunksize; ++i) {
    begin = x;
    end = y * i;
    setTimeout(createWaysChunk.bind(null, begin, end), 100);
    x = end;
  }
  t1 = performance.now();
  console.log("Call to createways = took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
}
// time out just moves the "freeze" to after the page loads
//var timeoutID0 = window.setTimeout(createWays, 2000);
window.onload = createWays;
// createWays();
t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to waypoints = took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

// Test with .enableAll
//t0 = performance.now();
//console.log('after 1');
// time out just moves the "freeze" to after the page loads
//var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Waypoint.enableAll, 2000);
//initial enabled = false then enable is way slow, slower than true overall by 15000+ ms
//Waypoint.enableAll();
//console.log('after 2');
//t1 = performance.now();
//console.log("Call to enableAll took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

```css
.facepunch {
  height: 3em;
  border: solid 1px lime;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js" integrity="sha256-jDnOKIOq2KNsQZTcBTEnsp76FnfMEttF6AV2DF2fFNE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="punchme"></div>
```

Comment: Note, shim `.bind(` if older browsers needed